# MS Publisher Automation

Tags: c#, silverlight, automation, publisher

I need to automate MS Publisher via a Silverlight OOB application to generate a publisher document. I have done some Excel automation via Silverlight starting from an example I found on this forum.  The following works

```
dynamic mspub = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Publisher.Application");
dynamic pubd = mspub.Documents.Add();
```

However, I don't really know how I can take things further.  I need to define styles, add images, add tables, add text... .  I would much appreciate any help.  What I lack above all is a decent reference to the various capabilities exposed by the MS Publisher automation object.

I would hugely appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify which version you are using however MSDN is the place to find reference on for all MS API's.

[Publisher 2007 Developer Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa434618%28v=office.12%29.aspx)
[Publisher 2010 Developer Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff940725.aspx)

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I needed. Strange, I tried a search on MSDN and the two links it came up with proved to be wholly useless. I guess, I was just trying the wrong keywords.

Comment: Hmmm... . I have looked at the documentation and it seems like its usage is not entirely painless. To help things out I worked backwards by creating a .PUB with one TextFrame and one Picture. By dint of some trial and error I found that these two objects turn up as Pages(1).Shapes(1|2). Shape(1) being my textframe I am then able to do 

Pages(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Hello World!";

However, I have yet to figure out how to get/set the picture in the second Shape.  If you can point me to some place ehre I can work through some clear example code I would be hugely grateful.